# HttpResponse rewrite before jackson serialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I want to know is there any way I can catch the controller returned response without a (`@Controlleradvice` or `HandlerInterceptor`) before passing it to the 
HttpServlet again, my intention is to add some custom serialization's to the response before serving the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [ContainerResponseFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html). All outgoing requests will pass through the filter and will provide the response context which will have the response body.

This is a good [sample](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.2/html/apache_cxf_development_guide/jaxrs20filters-serverresponsefilter)